# Javascript: Parse linear-gradient to array

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

`"linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 90, 95) 0%, rgb(78, 171, 255) 50%, rgb(1, 169, 141) 100%)"`

I would like to get the following output:

```
[[
    0,
    [255,90,95]
],
[
    50,
    [78,171,255]
],
[
    100,
    [1,169,141]
]]
```

What would be the easiest way to parse my string ? A regex capturing what's in-between "rgb" wouldn't be enough.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What problems have been encountered?

Comment: Why exactly wouldn't capturing the rgb value work? How else were you planning to do it?

Comment: True, will do an apologize to this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const regex = /rgb\((\d*), (\d*), (\d*)\) (\d*)%/g;
const str = `"linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 90, 95) 0%, rgb(78, 171, 255) 50%, rgb(1, 169, 141) 100%)"`;

const obj = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    obj.push([ parseInt(m[4]), [ parseInt(m[1]), parseInt(m[2]), parseInt(m[3]) ]]);
}
console.log(obj);
```